# System.Speech.Synthesis and Recognition on Windows 10 and 7

Tags: c#, windows, system.speech.recognition

I'm using `System.Speech.Synthesis;` and `System.Speech.Recognition;` in C# winform desktop application.

I have Window 10 on my notebook and default Adult male or female voice sounds different then on the PC with Windows 7.

If system voice works, but sounds completely  different on the older OS, how also this can  affect such  using as `System.Speech.Recognition;`  for example, with using on older system?

I guess I can't make any  update with executable  installation for not appropriate reference.

It is  hardly relevant to my question, but also I use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` initialization to use only English language for program. I note this because maybe there is some limited by particular system capability, but  exist way to fix this  somehow. Maybe I can load some updates with  assemble, but I'm not sure how big is update between window 10 and windows 7  for this particular references.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your question. But AFAIK, the 'voice' of Synthesiser will vary between different Windows versions, and there's not really much you can do about it other than to use some 3rd party library that provides text-to-speech or so

Comment: Hello, I just do not quite understand how this can affect the recognition using